Task Manager in PowerShell
I want to add icons to this, but I can’t figure out how to call the icons for each application. Any help would be greatly appreciated.
Note: I use this when I can’t access the remote computer’s UI, but can access a remote PowerShell interface.
# Create a new PowerShell form
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Windows.Forms
$form = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Form
$form.Text = "Task Manager"
$form.WindowState = "Maximized"
$form.FormBorderStyle = 'None'
$form.TopMost = $true

# Create a list box to display processes and services
$listBox = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.ListBox
$listBox.Dock = "Fill"
$listBox.TabIndex = 0
$form.Controls.Add($listBox)

# Create a button to refresh the list
$refreshButton = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Button
$refreshButton.Dock = "Bottom"
$refreshButton.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(75, 23)
$refreshButton.Text = "Refresh"
$refreshButton.TabIndex = 1
$refreshButton.Add_Click({ Update-ListBox })
$form.Controls.Add($refreshButton)

# Create a button to enable/disable a process or service
$enableButton = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Button
$enableButton.Dock = "Bottom"
$enableButton.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(95, 320)
$enableButton.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(75, 23)
$enableButton.Text = "Enable/Disable"
$enableButton.TabIndex = 2
$enableButton.Add_Click({ Enable-Disable })
$form.Controls.Add($enableButton)

# Create a button to exit the form
$exitButton = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Button
$exitButton.Dock = "Bottom"
$exitButton.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(310, 320)
$exitButton.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(75, 23)
$exitButton.Text = "Exit"
$exitButton.TabIndex = 3
$exitButton.Add_Click({ $form.Close() })
$form.Controls.Add($exitButton)

# Function to update the list box
function Update-ListBox {
    $listBox.Items.Clear()
    $processes = Get-Process
    $services = Get-Service
    foreach ($process in $processes) {
        $listBox.Items.Add("Process: $($process.Name) (ID: $($process.Id))")
    }
    foreach ($service in $services) {
        $listBox.Items.Add("Service: $($service.Name) (Status: $($service.Status))")
    }
}

# Function to enable/disable a process or service
function Enable-Disable {
    $itemName = $listBox.SelectedItem
    if ($itemName -like "Process:*") {
        $processName = $itemName -replace "Process: ", ""
        $process = Get-Process | Where-Object { $_.Name -eq $processName }
        if ($process -ne $null) {
            $action = [System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox]::Show("Do you want to enable or disable this process?", "Enable/Disable", [System.Windows.Forms.MessageBoxButtons]::YesNo)
            if ($action -eq "Yes") {
                Start-Process -FilePath $process.Path -ArgumentList $process.StartArguments
            } else {
                Stop-Process -Name $process.Name -Force
            }
        }
    } elseif ($itemName -like "Service:*") {
        $serviceName = $itemName -replace "Service: ", ""
        $service = Get-Service | Where-Object { $_.Name -eq $serviceName }
        if ($service -ne $null) {
            $action = [System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox]::Show("Do you want to start or stop this service?", "Enable/Disable", [System.Windows.Forms.MessageBoxButtons]::YesNo)
            if ($action -eq "Yes") {
                Start-Service -Name $service.Name
            } else {
                Stop-Service -Name $service.Name
            }
        }
    }
}

# Show the form
[void]$form.ShowDialog()

When I attempted to add
# Function to draw the list box items
function DrawItem($sender, $e) {
    $item = $sender.Items[$e.Index]
    $e.DrawBackground()
    $icon = $item.Icon
    $iconWidth = 16
    $iconHeight = 16
    $iconRect = New-Object System.Drawing.Rectangle($e.Bounds.X, $e.Bounds.Y, $iconWidth, $iconHeight)
    $e.Graphics.DrawIcon($icon, $iconRect)
    $e.Graphics.DrawString($item.Name, $sender.Font, [System.Drawing.Brushes]::Black, $e.Bounds.X + 20, $e.Bounds.Y)
    $e.DrawFocusRectangle()
}

I get an unhandled exception error for each application and service. I didn't get screenshots because this was not allowing me to access anything else. Not sure what I need to do. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

How are you routing/calling DrawItem?

As an aside: It's best to avoid pseudo method syntax: Instead of New-Object SomeType(arg1, ...), use New-Object SomeType [-ArgumentList] arg1, ... - PowerShell cmdlets, scripts and functions are invoked like shell commands, not like methods. That is, no parentheses around the argument list, and whitespace-separated arguments (, constructs an array as a single argument, as needed for -ArgumentList). However, method syntax is required if you use the PSv5+ [SomeType]::new() constructor-call method. See this answer for details.
